# Question about a step in the proof of Kolmogorov's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I was reading the proof of Kolmogorov's theorem in [this book](https://books.google.de/books/about/Functional_Integration_and_Quantum_Physi.html?id=6Wcaa2ddplEC&redir_esc=y) and there is a step which I don't follow. The statement of the theorem is the following.

> **Theorem** (Kolmogorov's theorem)**.** Let $\mathscr{I}$ be a countable set and let a probability measure $\mu_I$ on $\mathbb{R}^{\#(I)}$ be given for each finite set $I\subseteq\mathscr{I}$ so that the family of $\mu_I$'s is consistent. Then, there is a probability measure space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and random variables $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\mathscr{I}}$ so that $\mu_I$ is the joint probability distribution of $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$. Moreover, this space is unique in the sense that if $(X',\mathcal{F}',\mu')$ and $\{f'_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\mathscr{I}}$ also have these properties and if $\mathcal{F}$ (and respectively, $\mathcal{F}'$) is the smallest $\sigma$-field with respect to which the $f_\alpha$ (respectively, $f'_\alpha$) are measurable, then there is an isomorphism of the probability measure spaces under which each $f_\alpha$ corresponds to $f_\alpha'$.

After proving existence, the author wants to prove uniqueness (up to isomorphisms). The context is the following. We have a probability space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and random variables $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$, $I$ countable, defined as projections. What I mean is that $X = (\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\})^{I}$ the the cartesian product of one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f_{\alpha}(x) = x_{\alpha}$ if $x_{\alpha} \neq \infty$ and zero otherwise.

So far, so good. But then the author wants to prove that the space of bounded functions on $X$ depending on finitely-many entries $\{x_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ is dense in $L^{2}(X,d\mu)$. To do it, he takes an arbitrary set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and a sequence of functions $\{g_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges $g_{n} \to \chi_{A}$ in $L^{2}$. Here, $\chi_{A}$ is the characteristic function of $A$ ($=1$ if $x \in A$ and zero otherwise). One can find a subsequence $\{g_{n_{k}}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges pointwise to $\chi_{A}$ almost surely. Then he defines $A_{n} = \{x \in X: 1/2 < g_{n_{k}}(x) < 2\}$ and characteristic functions $\chi_{A_{n}} \equiv \chi_{n}$. Here is my problem: the author seems to claim that each $\chi_{A_{n}}$ depends only on finitely-many entries $x_{\alpha}$. But why is this the case? I can't convince myself.

[image: As it was pointed out in the comments that something was missing, I am adding a picture of part of the proof to clarify.]

Comment: You say 'a sequence of functions $\{g_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges $g_{n} \to \chi_{A}$ in $L^{2}$'. Clearly, some information about $g_n$ is missing.

Comment: Maybe I am getting the wrong message from the proof, but this is exactly what is written in the proof. No other properties of $g_{n}$ is mentioned.

Comment: I add a picture of some extraction of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The $g_n$ can be taken to depend on finitely many $f_\alpha$, by definition of $\mathscr H$.